# Getting ClassCastException

Tags: java, vector, hashtable, classcastexception

I am typecasting the object to a bean class ,which in turn gives me a exception ClassCastException,i am not getting the issue behind this.

```
 Hashtable listEvent = getEvents(label1.getText(), str);

  Enumeration events = listEvent.keys();
   while (events.hasMoreElements()) {
    String key = (String) events.nextElement();

    if (key.equals(label1.getText())) {

       Vector object = (Vector) listEvent.get(key);

       Enumeration hashtable = listEvent.keys();
        while (hashtable.hasMoreElements()) {
          String keys = (String) hashtable.nextElement();
           if (keys.equals(label1.getText())) {

  Vector data = (Vector) listEvent.get(keys);
       for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
      EventsBean bean1 = (EventsBean) data.elementAt(i);
```

I get an error while the running the application for typecasting to EventsBean.

Comment: Obviously `data` contains at least *some* elements that are not instances of type `EventsBean`.  What led you to believe that `data` would only contain that type?

Comment: Hard to guess, what does `System.out.println(data.elementAt(i).getClass())` print? Place it just before casting.

Comment: Why aren't you using generics, which should remove a bunch of these casts?

Comment: What do you have in listEvent Hashtable? From exception it is evident that you are trying to convert from some other class to EventsBean.

Comment: data has the values of type EventsBean only,because i am setting those

Comment: @user, you appear to be mistaken.

Comment: @user1195292, if that was actually true, then you wouldn't see this exception.  Something must be wrong there.

Comment: eventBean.setUserDate(usrDate);
                                                eventBean.setTimeZone(timezone);
                                               listEvents.addElement(eventBean);
   listUserEvents.put(usrDate, listEvents);

Comment: @KirkWoll i am setting as above then adding to vector and the vector is placed to hashtable

Comment: @KirkWoll My project entirely has Vector and Hashtable,how can i resolve this now,i cannot modify the project now,it will effect most classes,what can be the temporary fix for this?

Comment: @JonSkeet can i have a temporary fix for this?

Comment: @user1195292: Well we don't know what the *actual* type is, so it's hard to say why it's going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you used generic collections rather than raw types (`Map<String, List<EventsBean>>` instead of `Hashtable`), those errors would be caught by the compiler.

Forget about Vector, Hashtable and Enumeration. They should not be used anymore since Java 1.2.

And finally, why are you iterating on the hash table keys, instead of looking up the value directy?

Instead of

```
Enumeration events = listEvent.keys();
while (events.hasMoreElements()) {
    String key = (String) events.nextElement();
    if (key.equals(label1.getText())) {
       Vector object = (Vector) listEvent.get(key);
```

Just use

```
Vector object = (Vector) listEvent.get(label1.getText());
```

Now to answer your question: if you get a ClassCastException, it means that the objects stored in the collection are not what you think they are. Check the code which fills the collection. (and switch to generic, modern collections)

Comment: My project entirely has Vector and Hashtable,how can i resolve this now,i cannot modify the project now,it will effect most classes

Comment: temporary fix is not available ?

Comment: At least use Vector<EventsBean> and Hashtable<String, Vector<EventsBean>>.